# Flutter - Run code when a notification is received, without clicking it

Tags: flutter, notifications

Trying to show dialog in `onResume` or `onLaunch` without the user clicking the notification received from FCM

Something like **whatsApp and FB messenger calls**, they just show up on screen.

Can't find any way to accomplish this

Comment: have you find a solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

You have to take attention on **Data message** of the FCM documentation : 
[Receiving Messages](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages)

You need to configure both Android and iOS Projects to allow **background messages**. See [Android Integration](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#android-integration) and [iOS integration](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#ios-integration) for this

Comment: I'm asking about how to do that WITHOUT user clicking the notification.

Comment: Sry, I have edited my answer. In fact everything you need to know is on the package documentation. Hope you will success with it

Comment: This is not an answer.